# removing certain part of string from column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains a text column called 'Note'.

This column contains null values and some string values. The update query below was run on the table when it shouldn't have been.

```
update tblExample set Note = Note + ' USD Temp influx'
```

So the rows with null's in them haven't changed but the other rows have.

I want to remove this text from the field and leave any other text already in there remaining. What is the best way to do this?

Is it something like below but in an update query? Not sure how this should be written?

```
select replace(Note, ' USD Temp influx', '') from tblExample?
```

**update**

sorry should have said the column is a nvarchar type

Comment: Are you really using the text datatype? Or do you mean varchar? I ask because they are VERY different animals.

Comment: Doing a `replace` like that will also affect any rows that contain that text in the middle. If you are sure that text didn't already exist prior to the unwanted update, it will be fine.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry should have said its a nvarchar

Comment: @mHelpMe Is it `nvarchar(max)` or much smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
UPDATE tblExample
SET Note = replace(Note, ' USD Temp influx', '')
WHERE Note LIKE '% USD Temp influx'; 
-- it will replace all occurences in string (not only the last one)
```

or more secure way:

```
UPDATE tblExample
SET Note = LEFT(Note, LEN(Note) - 16)
WHERE Note LIKE '% USD Temp influx';
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/UATF62214)**

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It seems to be doing what the OP is asking.

Comment: @SeanLange Not if the column already contained that text, it will remove both occurrences which is potentially bad. The second block of SQL is fine though.

Comment: @DavidG I agree that the first one is potentially problematic.

Comment: @DavidG Sure, simple like will do, and I am aware it is not sargable :)

Comment: SARG isn't a problem here, pretty sure this is a one-off ad-hoc fix.

Comment: The first block is still a potential problem though.